# How to copy and transfer the variables of a typedef struct array to another - C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I currently have two 2D arrays of `typedef struct` named "drinks"

```
//Global Variable
int typenum = 0;
int typetotal = 0;
int classtotal = 0; 
/*..skipped other variables... */

typedef struct nodebase{
    char productname[254];
    char companyname[254];
    int productencoding;
    int rownum;
    int colnum;
    int price;
    struct nodebase *next;
}drinks;
```

/* Skipped the parts where typenum, typetotal, and classtotal will be used */

```
void copy_data(drinks a[3][100],drinks b[3][100],int typenum,int typetotal,int classtotal)
{
    memcpy(&b[typenum][classtotal],&a[typenum][typetotal],sizeof(drinks));
}
```

Assuming that `drinks a` certainly has all the data within its variables stated in `typedef struct`, I just want to "copy and paste" those data into `drinks b`.

But however, after compiling the code with VS2012 (Windows), `drinks b` is `NULL`. Any advice?

*Calling: `copy_data(a,b,typenum,typetotal,classtotal)`, assuming that I have `drinks a` and `drinks b` declared and initialized in the function where I will call `copy_data`

Comment: How is `copy_data` called?

Comment: Did you verify inside `copy_data` the value of `b`?

Comment: `sizeof(drinks)` will just give you the size of a single `struct`, and unless `typenum`, `classtotal`, and `typetotal` are all `0`, your starting points are almost certainly incorrect.

Comment: sizeof(drinks) returns the sizeof the structure drinks.
to copy the entire array do sizeof(drinks * array_size).

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Yes, they are all 0

Comment: @CasperVonB I am using 2D arrays so what are you referring to when you say `array_size`?

Comment: If `drinks b` is a 2D array as you say, I'm skeptical at the claim that it "is `NULL`". You need to present the shortest compilable example that you can demonstrating this problem, i.e. including a `main()` function containing the population of the array and the call to `copy_data()`, and leaving out everything that's not necessary to recreate the problem.

Comment: The `drinks b` should be allocated or defined as `drinks b[3][100]` in the calling procedure. If b is defined as `drinks** b` will not work.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths What I meant by `NULL` is that when I try to print the name of `b` like `printf(":||%s||: Name\n...);` nothing gets print except `:||||:`.

Comment: @BeginnerC: `b` is not a string, you can't `printf` a struct like that. This is why you need to show a complete compilable example, because the real issue is most likely that you're doing something weird like this that nobody here can possibly know unless you show us complete code.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths `printf(":||%s||: Name\n",b[typenum][classtotal].name` prints nothing

Comment: @BeginnerC: Like I said, please post complete compilable code so we can see what you're doing. Voting to close as unclear until then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assignment operator, but be careful with pointers contained within the structure:

```
void copy_data(drinks a[3][100],drinks b[3][100],int typenum,int typetotal,int classtotal)
{
    // Direct assignment
    b[typenum][classtotal] = a[typenum][typetotal];

    // This pointer will still be to the old list - probably needs updating?
    b[typenum][classtotal].Next = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `memcpy()` for this; use assignment:

```
void copy_data(drinks a[3][100], drinks b[3][100], int typenum, int typetotal, int classtotal)
{
    b[typenum][classtotal] = a[typenum][typetotal];
}
```

As to what your compiler's doing, it is not clear.  But if the code is similar to this:

```
int main(void)
{
    drinks a[3][100];
    drinks b[3][100];

    ...initialize b...
    copy_data(a, b, 1, 10, 20);
    ...check result...

}
```

there is no way that `b` can legitimately be a null pointer in the `copy_data` function.  If it is null, you have a serious divergence between what I wrote and what you wrote.

Comment: Will assignement even copy all the data of the `typedef struct` of `a` into `b`?

Comment: Of course; structures can be assigned.  Once upon a very, very, very long time ago, structure copying was not supported, but we're talking about circa 1980.  I never worked on a C compiler without structure copying, but it was a new feature in the compiler when I started using them.